# How to make a type for a joined list of strings?

Tags: typescript

I have two types for string literals:

```
type ItemA = `${string}:${number}`;
type ItemB = `${string}:${number},${number}`;
```

I may have a mixed array of literals of both types (ItemA and ItemB).

At some point I receive a string where this array elements are joined in a single string.

```
type ItemAB = ItemA | ItemB;

function parseItemsAB(itemsABjoined: string): ItemAB[] {
  return itemsABjoined.split(' ');
}
```

How better define the type for `itemsABJoined`?

Comment: Those `ItemA` and `ItemB` are unfortunate types because they accept spaces, but you are going to split on spaces, so you might split individual items into pieces.  Also note that `\`${number}\`` can hold all kinds of fun strings like `"-9.5e+7"`, which I don't know if you want to support.  What are the actual constraints on `ItemA` and `ItemB`?

Comment: There is no specific type in TypeScript corresponding to "a bunch of `ItemA | ItemB`s joined by spaces, so the only approach would be to make `parseItemsAB` *generic*, as shown in [this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/NaEbyN). Does that meet your needs? If so I could write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: ItemA and ItemB will not contain spaces. (I know how to improve their typings for that.) As for the numbers, I would like them to be integers without exponential notation.

Comment: Thank you for the `parseItemsAB`, I think this is what I can use! Would you please write it as an answer so I could rate it? And (optionally) could you please explain how it works? 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no specific type in TypeScript corresponding exactly to the set of possible outputs of `items.join(" ")` where `items` is of type `ItemAB[]` where `ItemAB` is assignable to `string`.  There is an open feature request at [microsoft/TypeScript#41160](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/41160) to support *regular expression validated string types* but it's not part of the language as of TypeScript 5.0.

Instead, if you need to deal with such a type, you can represent it as a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) constraint instead of a specific type.  That is, instead of `type ItemsABJoined = ...`, you write `type ItemsABJoined<T extends string> = ...`, where `T extends ItemsABJoined<T>` is true if and only if `T` is valid, and if it's invalid, then `ItemsABJoined<T>` is a valid string which is "close" to `T` in some sense, so that error messages are hopefully helpful.

Here's one approach:

```
type DemoItemAB = 'abc:123' | 'def:234,567'

type ItemsABJoined<T extends string, A extends string = ""> =
    T extends `${infer F} ${infer R}` ? 
    (F extends ItemAB ? ItemsABJoined<R, `${A}${F} `> : `${A}${DemoItemAB}`) :
    `${A}${T extends ItemAB ? T : DemoItemAB}`
```

`ItemsABJoined<T, A>` is a [tail-recursive conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-5.html#tail-recursion-elimination-on-conditional-types) that uses [conditional type inference](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#inferring-within-conditional-types) on [template literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/template-literal-types.html) to parse `T`, and accumulate the output type in the accumulator `A`.  (`A` starts out by [default](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-3.html#generic-parameter-defaults) as the empty string literal type `""` and progressively grows by having things appended to it.)

If there is a space in `T`, then it is split into the first part of the string `F` before the first space, and the rest of the string `R` after the first space.  If `F` is a valid `ItemAB`, then things are fine so far and we can keep going by evaluating `` ItemsABJoined<R, `${A}${F} `> ``... that is, add `F` and a space to the accumulator and parse the rest of the string.  If `F` is *not* a valid `ItemAB`, then we give up and return the currently accumulated string with some example `ItemAB` type appended to it.  (The `DemoItemAB` type is assignable to `ItemAB`... we can't just use `ItemAB` itself because of the problem that it accepts values with spaces in them; the pattern type `` `${string}` `` accepts spaces.  So if we did that then some invalid strings would be seen as valid.)

Anyway, if there is no space in `T`, then we don't need to recurse anymore.  The entire string is the last element, and can be checked against `ItemAB`.  If it matches, then we return the accumulator with `T` appended to it.  If not, then we return the accumulator with an example `ItemAB` type appended to it.

Let's see how this behaves with some tests:

```
type Good0 = ItemsABJoined<"abc:123">;
// type Good0 = "abc:123"
type Good1 = ItemsABJoined<"abc:123,456">;
// type Good1 = "abc:123,456"
type Good2 = ItemsABJoined<"abc:123,456 def:789">;
// type Good2 = "abc:123,456 def:789"
type Good3 = ItemsABJoined<"abc:123,456 def:789 ghi:012,3 j:0 z:2">
// type Good3 = "abc:123,456 def:789 ghi:012,3 j:0 z:2"

type Bad0 = ItemsABJoined<"oops">
// type Bad0 = "abc:123" | "def:234,567"
type Bad1 = ItemsABJoined<"o:0 whoops">
//type Bad1 = "o:0 abc:123" | "o:0 def:234,567"
type Bad2 = ItemsABJoined<"o:0 x:3 duh z:2">
// type Bad2 = "o:0 x:3 abc:123" | "o:0 x:3 def:234,567"
```

Looks reasonable.  The good inputs result in identical outputs, while the bad inputs result in good outputs that start the same as their input.

---

Now we can write `parseItemsAB()` as a generic function:

```
function parseItemsAB<T extends string>(itemsABjoined: ItemsABJoined<T>): ItemAB[] {
    return itemsABjoined.split(' ') as ItemAB[];
}
```

Note that I used a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) to tell the compiler that `itemsABJoined.split(' ')` will produce an `ItemAB[]`.  The compiler is nowhere near clever enough to understand that the output will be of that type; it doesn't understand what `split()` does in deatil; all it knows is that it outputs a `string[]`.  We have to assert that it's also a `ItemAB[]`.

And now we can call it.  These work:

```
console.log(parseItemsAB("abc:123")); // okay
console.log(parseItemsAB("abc:123,456")); // okay
console.log(parseItemsAB("abc:123,456 def:789")); // okay
console.log(parseItemsAB("abc:123,456 def:789 ghi:012,3 j:0 z:2")); // okay
```

while these result in compiler errors:

```
parseItemsAB("oops"); // error!
parseItemsAB("o:0 whoops"); // error!
parseItemsAB("o:0 x:3 duh z:2"); // error!
```

the error on the last one, for example, looks like:

```
// Argument of type '"o:0 x:3 duh z:2"' is not assignable to 
// parameter of type '"o:0 x:3 abc:123" | "o:0 x:3 def:234,567"'.
```

which is hopefully enough for the caller to realize that the problem starts at `"duh"`.

---

So that's the answer to the question as asked.

There are surely more complicated versions of `ItemsABJoined<T>` where the output to an invalid input is even "closer" to the input, so that `"o:0 x:3 duh z:2"` might produce, for example, `` `o:0 x:3 duh:${number} z:2` | `o:0 x:3 duh:${number},${number} z:2` ``, but I don't want to digress by going any further down that path... if you need such things, you could implement them; otherwise, this should be enough to proceed.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?useDefineForClassFields=true&target=9&noErrorTruncation=true#code/C4TwDgpgBAksEFsCCUC8UAGASA3gZ2ACcBLAOwHMBfALl1IFcEAjCQyjAbgChRJZ4EAITSZcBEhRp1GLNgBppzVu249w0OIiTD0m5FAA+-RIO69oAEUQB7PdpEByAIZMAxtQCMAJgDMDw1AOACYQAGbUvgAscgCsAGwA7A5canx6eNoAUtZkEEEAPAAqUBAAHvCkQXhQ4mTkclAoZRVVNUR1IgBEnQB8aFxQg1DFzRCV1dg4ZKGsUABilFC407MASuxQAPwDQwAUcyXlY612wpvGCBmC2bkFqw2TSJS4C5h91KI4T7hWCLYC2nYAEooNQdoNHs8cCMjuMLvZzsUPr9-lpBOwUilzFAAOLWaxBAAMInSWRypDy+U6Lnc3h8vW4AHpGVBsXiCcT0NS3J5fJ1UtB2UEPCSBFcbhSCtzab45JF4gyuMzWepcfjhV0abyfHKFQK1QSvKLEOLyZTpdrdXEoCFwgkABwATkVyrZ6qNXK1dKtNrC1Adzv1Qp8xsuZNuVK9svl1tt-qdUHIAAtiNRCd45CGAFZpqAALwivSVLLdBJDnp53pjvrtCeTqfTXkzUBzxILXn5+sETiJodNEc6+LAeCLrtV3d7FZl9ICnTjUViiX52InIt0YvDkqp1lzAHck0ORz1iyue2uoIPc1GZ0ZL8T5z5ovEEsvxz2PRd+1u71BStQQ0E9BJvmhbHmOfATh+P5-iG16dLOO7EjBNYRI+i4vpioT0KQrjAMQ1ikFAYBOIQeAQKSghFIcLTVLUFA9LsxAboIWZmkEHwURKlKFD0QIcQCggANoALpQDg4JQIQEDAPQhCEUxJraKxtwAHR4GAAA2TG7P4Dggk41SnCJ3CUFwrgEXg1gaRAKkadY5C7MRpHkcxuwWnSnRAkCHBQMq1gANZOCAZkWVZNl2Q5TlkRRbnXlanneb5LIBUFIWkJZ1m2fZjkkdFrnudG8QoQGCU+X5gXBeZ6VhVlkW5S5imCLFlaFbGfoBomKZphm2a5u2pVJVAKXBVwUUNWGTWDtYw6eWVLKsIQ1iEAAhKN9UxT++6HrNg0LUtq1jRtiG-v+NpASBHaJcqe0rVwQA)